# NSFetchRequest predicate with dates within the last 24 hours?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a Core Data entity named `RSSItem` with a Date attribute named `publicationDate`.

Is there a way to create a predicate for a `NSFetchRequest` that would include all entities with a publication date in the last 24 hours?

I have tried this:

```
NSString* expression = @"publicationDate.timeIntervalSinceNow >= -86400";
return [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:expression];
```

But that yields a `nil` predicate, thus matching everything.

I would like to have a live predicate that change over time. Therefor a predicate with a `NSDate` instance is not possible, since it defines an immutable single point in time, not a relative time such as *the last 24 hours*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Relative date is not a problem. You don't need the predicate to change. The 'last 24 hour' boundary is a fixed point in time relative to the current time. Create an `NSDate` and stick it in the predicate (like in Robert's answer above)
- For "live-ness", you could use a fetched property with the above predicate, putting the cutoff date/time in the userInfo dictionary. The results are cached by CoreData (because true live properties would cause a DB query each time, and could be expensive) so you need to call      `NSManagedObjectContext refreshObject:` to update the data (say, whenever you're finished inserting a bunch of new `RSSItem`s after a refresh).

Answer (score 4):

I think this should work:

`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"publicationDate >= %@", [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-86400];`

#### Update

You could try an alternate approach to get the live predicate to work. I think that you have to update the attribute(s) for an entity that are used in a predicate to trigger a filtering anyway so even if your proposed predicate was possible you would still have to loop through all items and fake an update for `publicationDate`.

What you could try is add a bool attribute `shouldDisplay` to `RSSItem` and a method `updateShouldDisplay'

```
- (void)updateShouldDisplay {
    self.shouldDisplay = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[self.publicationDate compare:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-86400]] == NSOrderedDescending];
}
```

Then whenever you are refreshing the RSS feed you loop through all entities and call `updateShouldDisplay`. You probably have to call `updateShouldDisplay` from `awakeFromFetch` as well.

And just to be complete the predicate would look like:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"shouldDisplay == YES"]
```

I'm not 100% on this but I think you can't use transient properties in an NSPredicate which means you have to store `shouldDisplay`.

Comment: I should update my question, I would like to have a live query that updates the result set over time. My bad for missing this quite important piece of info.